# Sharing a google sheet and preserving protections/formulas

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to share a google sheet while preserving the protected cells or hiding the formulas so they cannot be viewed or edited? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to use `IMPORTRANGE` in secondary spreadsheet you will share while your sheet remains private